# Don't clone git repository via composer

Tags: git, composer-php

I am trying composer from packagist.org and a git repository for managing versions of my library. When I required my library, composer cloned the repository to vendor folder, but I need only download files. Here's my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "vend/xxxxxx",
    "description": "SDK for quick creation of client integration",
    "keywords": [
        "xxxxxxx",
        "sdk"
    ],
    "homepage": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "DDelivery": "application/classes"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0.*@dev"
        }
    }
}
```

and composer.json 2:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vend/xxxxxx": "2.0.*@dev"
    }
}
```

What am I missing from my composer.json? How can I manage my versions through git and packagist.org? How do other vendors manage their frameworks?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I need only download files"? Looks like files are downloaded to your `vendor` dir (which is correct behavior).

Comment: I want just download files to vendor directory, but files download with .git/ directory

Answer (score 2):

By default, stable versions are downloaded and unstable versions are cloned. You can customize this behaviour with the `--prefer-dist` or `--prefer-source` flags of the `update` and `install` command.

Comment: This is only true for locations where Composer knows the download link, like Github or Bitbucket. Everywhere else, Composer can only clone the repository unless there is metadata added to point it to a download file.

Comment: How can I publish stable version? For example, developers of Yii2 framework have stable versions on composer, but in their repository I can't find matches with their branches on repository. How do they publish stable versions? when I publish my work on packagist.org they allow me only insert my repository url ...

Comment: @user2468946 branches are seen as dev versions. To have stable versions, create a tag (or "release" as GitHub calls it). These can be seen on the `/releases` URL on GitHub (e.g. for Yii2: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases)